# "Someone" and "somebody": one or many?

Tags: meaning

Is it correct that *somebody* may imply many people or an organization as a whole?

Particularly, can I think that *someone* assumes only one person whereas *somebody* can be said about a group of persons as well?

Comment: Moudrick, you shouldn't have posted a new question; you should have revised your previous question.  In answer to your latest question, both _someone_ and _somebody_ are pronouns that, grammatically, refer to singular subjects/objects.  If these pronouns are used in questions, it is correct to answer with singular or plural nouns, for example: _Can somebody/someone help me?_  _Yes, Johnny can_.  OR:   _Yes, Johnny and Amanda can_.

Comment: Actually, they are two different questions. Editing a question to completely change it is not something that should be suggested, especially when there is already an answer.

Comment: As far as I have been able to understand the stackexchange ethos, in fact Moudrick has rendered both of his questions less useful to future users because he has unnecessarily divided up his question into two (instead of clarifying it as one question).  I am trying to play by the rules and acclimatize.  How about you, kiamlaluno?

Comment: I stand down.  Everytime you and I get into an interesting debate, it immediately becomes personal.   I look forward to the day when we can passionately discuss grammar and the English language and put previous disagreements aside.  So far, you have seemed unwilling to do so.

Answer (score 2):

*Somebody* is a synonym of *someone*; both are used to mean "a person who is not known or mentioned by name."

I can say "there is somebody at the door," or "there is someone at the door"; in the first case, it doesn't mean there is surely more than one person, nor does the second case mean there is surely just one person. Similarly, if I say "there is somebody at the door," I am not supposing there is more than a person; if I am supposing it, that is not expressed by using *somebody* instead of *someone*.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, both "someone" and "somebody" are singular.

Let me add a few extra thoughts:

In English we sometimes use the singlular to refer to a representative member of a group, without necessarily meaning that there is only one person in the group. For example, suppose I said, "This new motor is so light that someone can lift it with one hand". I don't mean that there is only one person in the world who can lift it with one hand, but that a typical or representative person can do this.

If you want to make clear that you have many people in mind, use a plural word. For example, if you said, "Is there someone here who can help me unload the truck?", people hearing you would understand this to mean that you are looking for one person to help. If you wanted to make clear that this is a job that will require several people, you might say, "Are there some people here who can help me unload the truck?", or some such phrasing.

I see one poster notes that a question phrased in the singular might get a plural answer. This is true, but not really specific to singular and plural. Any answer might not exactly match the question. Like if you asked, "Does that kangaroo over there belong to you?", someone might answer, "That wallaby over there belongs to me." Depending on the context, such a rejection of an assumption built into a question may be pointed or casual.